# Mongodb best practices for multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, database-design

On a forum type website, I have two collections that are closely related to each other. `users` and `likes`.

```
likes: {
  _id:5fa9ba086259f619f7d9f82b
  postId:"7A0A"
  author:"e3fc0911-b708-481e-b4fb-8c1c60a57c3d"
}

user: {
  _id:"51c6cc3b-6951-45c5-bf07-cfe86fccbbd5"
  username:"sun"
}
```

Every time I fetch a user I would like to show the number of likes that user has in total . Until now I have solved this with projection. I would get the author. Get the amount of likes and combine it using projection.

```
[{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'likes',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'author',
        as: 'likes'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        author: 1,
        username: 1,
        likeAmount: {
            $size: '$likes'
        },
    }
}]
```

This returns the user object with the number of likes for a specific user.

It has worked fairly well until I started adding more features. New feature is posts. Now with each post I would want to query the author of the post, and with the author the likes. This starts to become more and more complicated with every feature.

I fear that soon I will hit a limit of nested references where I cant interact with the projected data anymore.

`Idea1`: break up the API calls on the frontend. So post would not get user with it automatically. Frontend would have to fetch post first. Then ask for user based on userId.

`Idea2`: keep a running likeAmount property in User, it would get increased with every like for the given user. (more fields to keep updated, duplicate data)

Whats the best way to deal with structures like this in mongodb?

Comment: with the second option how would I query if the current user has upvoted a certain post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is rather cryptic, but I believe you want an advice on how to organize the collections.

- One of the Anti-patterns is to store separate things you normally query together.

If you say "every time I want a user I also want the likes", that should be in the same collection.

- Atlas and Compass show you Anti-patterns.

They classify your queries after you query the DB enough times, and tell you if there is something wrong.

---

If you do need to lookup+filter, there is a neat way using:

```
{
   $graphLookup: {
      from: <collection>,
      startWith: <expression>,
      connectFromField: <string>,
      connectToField: <string>,
      as: <string>,
      maxDepth: 0,
      restrictSearchWithMatch: <document>
   }
}
```

Where  is your query, ex. `{abdominals:null}`. I purposely set maxDepth:0 because it seems you could use it, but maxDepth is just `<number>`

Remember though that lookups may be undesirable for fast applications.

MongoDB has a [video on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CZs-0it9r4).